# How can I re-assign a value to an object variable from the object itself in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, this, variable-assignment

I'm creating a class with string validating methods. I cannot re-assign a value to the object reference like this:

```
class clearText
{
    private $text;

    function __construct($input)
    {
        $this->text = $input;
    }

    public function clearUp()
    {
        // …
        // functions to sanitize the string in $this->text
        // …
        $this = $this->text;
    }
}

$content = new clearText($_POST['content']);
$content->clearUp();
```

as the above example outputs:

> **Fatal error**:  Cannot re-assign $this in **\clearText.php** on line **13**

When I call `clearUp()`, I don't need the object anymore, so I would like to avoid specifying this assignment like here, every time I call the method:

```
$content = new clearText($_POST['content']);
$content->clearUp();
$content = $content->text;
```

Is there any way to do this *inside the method*?

---

### A possible answer

Somebody suggested returning the value, so I can re-assign it to the object variable in the same statement, that execute the method. The answer has since been deleted, but it works for what I need.

Method definiton:

```
public function clearUp()
{
    // …
    // functions to sanitize the string in $this->text
    // …
    return $this->text;
}
```

When instantiated:

```
$content = new clearText($_POST['content']);
$content = $content->clearUp();
```

Comment: It would not make sense that an *object* can transform itself into a primitive data type. However, you could override the `__toString` method of the class.

Comment: I must admit that I have no clue why you even tried to modify `$this` object reference. If you don't need the object, use a static class with static methods.

Comment: Of course I do more with the object than just calling one method. Still I might have overrated the idea of keeping to only functional or object-oriented code in one project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `clearUp()` method, call `unset()`. Assign the string to another variable before though. However, this will also ensure that any memory used by the `clearText` object is released:

```
$content = new clearText($_POST['content']);
$content = $content->text;
```

Comment: `clearUp()` has several functions (for filtering the string in `$text`) that I noted in the comment. (I will make it more clear in the question.) I only want to *include* the re-assignment of the holding variable.

Answer (score 0):

No. `$this` is the actually instance of the class that you're dealing with. You can't set it to any other value ever. It's a 'magic' keyword if you will.

Much like how you can't set the word `private` to mean something else.

You can destroy your instance by deleting `$content` however.